# Let $A=(0,1)\cup (1,2]$ be a subset of $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{U})$. Find A' (limit point) and $A \cup A'$

Tags: general-topology

For A' I got

$\mathbb{R}-(0,1)\cup (1,2]$

For $A \cup A'$ I got

$\mathbb{R}$

But I don't think thats right? Can anyone help me with explaining how to find these?

Comment: Is $0$ a limit point?

Answer (score 1):

$A'$ is defined to be $\{x ∈ X: (∀U \text{ neighborhood of } x): A ∩ U \setminus \{x\} ≠ ∅\}$. Here we have $A = (0, 1) ∪ (1, 2] ⊆ \mathbb{R} = X$. Obviously $A' ⊆ \overline{A}$. On the other hand $A$ does not contain any isolated point so $A' = \overline{A} = [0, 2]$.